# Does any module with finite number of elements have a simple submodule?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Does any module with finite number of elements have a simple submodule?

Not sure if this is true or not, struggling to find a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A module $M$ is simple if and only if every cyclic submodule generated by a nonzero element of $M$ equals M.

Let $A$ be a module with finite number of elements. Select a nonzero element $a\in A$ such that the submodule $\langle a\rangle < A$ (the element $a$ can be found, otherwise $A$ iteself is simple). Then select a nonzero $a_1 \in \langle a\rangle$ such that $\langle a_1 \rangle< \langle a\rangle$. Continue in this manner, you can obtain a simple submodule.

Comment: By $\langle a\rangle < A$ do you mean the submodule generated by the element a which is contained in A?

Comment: Yes. $\langle a \rangle$ is a submodule generated by $a$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer really helped

Answer (score 4):

Any nonzero module of finite cardinality has a simple submodule: Amongst all nonzero submodules, choose one of minimal cardinality.

The statement generalizes to Artinian modules $M$. The descending chain condition is equivalent to every nonempty family of submodules containing minimal elements (with respect to set inclusion). Applied to all nonzero submodules of $M$, it yields a simple submodule of $M$.

Answer (score 3):

Any finite partially ordered set has at least a minimal element.

In this case the partially ordered set is the one of the nonzero submodules.